# How to right-click to paste in mcedit

Tags: bash, vim, text-editors, midnight-commander, nano

On a bash terminal I can right-click to paste to vim or nano, but mcedit does not receive my clipboard data on right-click.

How to right-click to paste in mcedit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my own way. I'm using bash terminal on Windows, on title bar there's an icon on left side, clicking on it shows a menu.

Copy to system clipboard: menu >> edit >> copy

Paste to mcedit: menu >> edit >> paste

Answer (score 0):

I found my own way. I'm using bash terminal on Windows, on title bar there's an icon on left side, clicking on it shows a menu.

Comment: The question is “How to right-click to paste in mcedit?”  Can you explain how your post addresses that question? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.